# JsonSerializer.GetMatchingConverter (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] converters, System.Type objectType)

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am getting this error occasionally in multiple areas while deserializing the API response

Stack traces

Newtonsoft.Json
JsonSerializer.GetMatchingConverter (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] converters, System.Type objectType)

Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization
DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract)

Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization
DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract (System.Type objectType)

Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization
DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract (System.Type objectType)

System.Collections.Concurrent
ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory)

Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities
ThreadSafeStore`2[TKey,TValue].Get (TKey key)

Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization
DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract (System.Type type)

Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization
JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetContractSafe (System.Type type)

Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization
JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent)

Newtonsoft.Json
JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType)

Newtonsoft.Json
JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType)

Newtonsoft.Json
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings)

Newtonsoft.Json
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings)

Newtonsoft.Json
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value)

TSP.APIService
UsersService.GetDistrictsAndWards ()

```
            try 
            { 
                var response = (HttpResponseMessage)await _restClient.CallApiAsync(EndPoint, "GET", null, HeaderParams); 
                if (response != null && (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)) 
                { 
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResult<List<DistrictsandWardsResponse>>>(content); 
                    return result;
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    ViewModelLocator.TrackAPIException(EndPoint, httpResponse); 
                } 
                return default(APIResult<List<DistrictsandWardsResponse>>); 
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                ViewModelLocator.TrackException(ex);
            }
```

Comment: You could post the relevant code so that we could try to find out the cause .

Comment: You have included the traceback, but what is the exception type and message?  [`JsonSerializer.GetMatchingConverter(IList<JsonConverter>? converters, Type objectType)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs#L1201) doesn't seem to intentionally throw an exception in a release build.

Comment: Getting the exception type as System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000066 from typeref (expected class 'System.VewSeType' in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e') assembly:mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e type:System.VewSeType member:(null)

Comment: ` try
  {
     var response = (HttpResponseMessage)await _restClient.CallApiAsync(EndPoint, "GET", null, HeaderParams);
  if (response != null && (response.IsSuccessStatusCode))
  {
      var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResult<List<DistrictsandWardsResponse>>>(content);
             return result;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewModelLocator.TrackAPIException(EndPoint, httpResponse);
     }
     return default(APIResult<List<DistrictsandWardsResponse>>);
     }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    }`

Comment: Edit your question (click the 'edit' link) to add your information.